# How to move object dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object like below.

`[{id: 1, value: 'text1'},{id: 2, value: 'text2'},{id: 3, value: 'text3'}]`

I want to modify it to

`[{id: 1, value: 'text3'},{id: 2, value: 'text1'},{id: 3, value: 'text2'}]`

and reverse as

`[{id: 1, value: 'text2'},{id: 2, value: 'text3'},{id: 3, value: 'text1'}]`

conditionally and dynamically in a function ie, without changing the 'id' i need to modify the array as above using javascript. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example code.

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 'text1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 'text2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  value: 'text3'
}];

function transform(data, mode) {
  const dataClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  const arrClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataClone));
  return dataClone.map((item, index) => {
    let newValue;
    if (mode === 'reverse') {
      newValue = index === 0 ?
        arrClone[arrClone.length - 1].value :
        arrClone[index - 1].value
    } else {
      newValue = index === arrClone.length - 1 ?
        arrClone[0].value :
        arrClone[index + 1].value
    }
    item.value = newValue;
    return item;
  });
}

console.log('forward', transform(data, 'forward'));
console.log('reverse', transform(data, 'reverse'));
```